# Discord PY not getting user Avatar

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot and I cant get the avatar. I updated to V2 of Discord PY but avatars don't work, I am using all intents and its all set in developer portal. It was working before the update, any ideas?

```
@commands.command(aliases=["Avatar"])
async def avatar(self, ctx, member : discord.Member):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    userAvatar = member.avatar_url
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Avatar", description="", color=0xffff00)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=userAvatar)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=when_mentioned_or_function(get_prefix), help_command=None, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you updated to v2 of discord.py you can use the new [display_avatar](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.display_avatar) option, which is more complete than the previous avatar_url and avoids returning `None`.

```py
...
userAvatar = member.display_avatar
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Avatar", description="", color=0xffff00)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=userAvatar.url)
...
```

Comment: Ty so much it works now!

Answer (score 0):

**PREFIX COMMAND AVATAR**

```
@bot.command(aliases=['av', 'pfp']) #Aliases - nicknames of command
async def avatar(ctx,  *, member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None: #if no member is mentioned while using command
    member = ctx.author # member will be considered as msg author
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00000)#creating an embed
  embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)#sets img as pfp of member
  await ctx.send(embed=embed) #send the resulting embed in channel
```

**DOCUMENTATION FOR EMBEDS** - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_image

**DOCUMENTATION FOR AVATAR** - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=avatar#discord.Member.avatar_url

**SLASH COMMAND AVATAR**

```
@slash.slash_command( #This slash command does the same as above
    guild_ids=servers, # create a server list and put in all ids in order to make ur slash updates fast , since global updates take 1 hr to update
    name="avatar",#name of command
    description="See an avatar of an user", #description of command
    options=[
        Option("user", "which member's avatar you wanna see ?", 
OptionType.USER #Option should be in mentions
        required=True  #its not a optional , its required
        ),
    ]
)  
async def avatar(ctx, user):  # same command as the prefix command
embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00000)
embed.set_image(url=user.avatar_url)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Hope... You like my answer...

### SORRY FOR NOT SENDING EXPLANATION BEFORE

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Sorry , i understand that "a code only answer is not a solution" .  I am just new , I will  make sure that i will make explanations in my future answers